# Inter VLAN routing on HP Procurve 2610

Tags: routing, vlan

I have a network composed of:

- 1 x Cisco RV082 that gives access to the internet to the whole network
- 1 x Cisco UC560 PBX
- 1 x HP ProCurve 2610-PWR Switch

I have 2 VLANs

- VLAN 1 default/untagged - Data network (192.168.90.X / 255.255.255.0)
- VLAN 100 tagged - Voice network for the UC560 + Cisco Phones (10.1.1.X / 255.255.255.0)

I can't ping from 192.168.90.X the 10.1.1.1 subnet.

How could I ping 10.1.1.X from 192.168.90.X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further details regarding the configuration of the 2610 and the logical topology, I can only provide suggestions.

- Have you verified the physical interface status and duplex settings
  of the device(s) you are attempting to exchange ICMP between? If so, is there anything on the endpoints in the data network that may be blocking ICMP traffic by default, such as a Window's firewall?
- If your devices in the data network (192.168.90.0/24) are using the IP address of VLAN 1 for their default gateway, and the phones/PBX in the voice network (10.1.1.0/24) are using the IP address of VLAN 100 for their default gateway, then VLANs 1 and 100 should be configured with IP addresses allowing the HP ProCurve to perform inter-VLAN routing, which I'm sure you're well aware. You can issue the `show ip route` command to verify the connected routes exist to your VLAN 1 and 100 subnets.
- Additionally, there are some devices that do not support/understand
  802.1q frames, aka '*tagged*' frames. It would be worth checking the ARP table with the `show arp` command, following an attempted ICMP
  echo request from both sides, to ensure layer-3 to layer-2 resolution is working.
- If ICMP is failing between devices within VLAN 100, you may need to
  modify the configuration to `vlan 100 untagged [port-port]`. However,
  if your phones can ping each other and the PBX, I don't suspect the
  tagged VLAN is the issue.
- Another variable is the RV082 and whether or not it's performing all
  layer-3 duties (routing) and acting as a 'router on a stick' (serving
  as the default gateway for the 192.168.90.0/24 and 10.1.1.0/24
  subnets). In that case the interface on the 2610 that the RV082
  connects to will need to be tagged for VLAN 1 and 100, or untagged
  for VLAN 1 and tagged for 100 (depending on how the RV082 is
  configured)...and the VLANs would not require IP addresses for the
  sake of routing, but can still be used for the sake of management.